# How to find intersections in binary image lines?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a binary image with curved lines as shown below, but I would like to know how I can find where they would intersect if they are extended.

So could you give me some ides on how i could:

- extend the line endpoints in the same direction,
- how to find the intersections?

I have thought about using hough transform to find lines, then intersection, but in some images my line endpoints are not exactly straight.  Is there a way to maybe only find the direction of the line at the end of it instead of over the whole line, as it is a binary image?

Thanks for any help 
[image: c]
[image: a] [image: b]

Comment: You can take the good advice given below, but if you tell us more about your global problem, it may turn out there's an even better overall solution than finding these intersections directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying a dilation and then an erosion will extend your endpoints like this:

```
(*Code in Mathematica*)
Erosion[Dilation[i, 10], 10]
```

[image]

A full solution could be something like this:

```
r = Dilation[MorphologicalBranchPoints[
   Thinning[Binarize@Erosion[Dilation[i, 10], 10], 10]] // Colorize, 3]
ImageAdd[i, r]
```

[image]

Comment: That should work reasonably well when all the gaps to be filled are of a similar, known, size. Adaptively growing endpoints may be necessary in other scenarios. One idea would be to iteratively extend segments at endpoints in the local direction of the segment.

Comment: @Matthias Yours is a nice idea, and I think it could benefit from the notion of _scale_ (not a trivial thing to do).

Answer (score 4):

I think you should take a look at [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). It calculates lines equations from binary reprentation (usually output of edge detector). Once you have this, it is a piece of cake to calculate intersections.

Comment: +1 However, the downside is that the Hough transform will look for (and assume) straight lines. The OP appears to be looking for some sort of spline approximation(?) to rather arbirtrary curves, which is naturally somewhat more difficult.

Comment: It would be nice to show how to compute the intersections given the Hough transform output.

Comment: Hough transform will not work with my application as most of my lines are alot more curved that the sample image i provided

Comment: I added another few examples to my question

Answer (score 3):

You could try to fit three corresponding curves and then solve the equation for the two intersections explicitely.

There exist some established models for curve fitting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with using Hough Transform:

```
%# read and binarize image
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlxmL.jpg');
BW = im2bw(rgb2gray(I));

%# hough transform, detect peaks, then get lines segments
[H T R] = hough(BW, 'Theta',-10:10);   %# specific theta range
P  = houghpeaks(H, 5);
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P);

%# overlay detected lines over image
figure, imshow(BW), hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'g.-', 'LineWidth',2);
end

%# find endpoints (intersections) and show them
xy = [vertcat(lines.point1);vertcat(lines.point2)];
[~,idx1] = min(xy(:,2));
[~,idx2] = max(xy(:,2));
xy = xy([idx1;idx2],:);     %# intersection points
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2), 'ro', 'LineWidth',3, 'MarkerSize',12)
hold off
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but what about an image that has more curved lines? Such as the second one i added http://i.stack.imgur.com/NaHiI.jpg

Comment: my solution was fine-tuned for that first image. You could try playing around with the parameters of the Hough transform for the others, but I think [morphological operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f18-9530.html) might be better suited in the general case (similar to @belisarius solution)...

Answer (score 1):

Simply looking at your lines, they are more or less straight lines (not concave/convex curves) In my humble opinion, there's an easier way and more obvious way, since, you know either end points of the three lines.  You can always get the intersection by solving x and y respectively.

http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoLines1/intersectionOfTwoLines1.html

gd luck

Answer (score 0):

fill contours into `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >` ,  using findContours function from OpenCV library, then for any two contours which don't intersect ( case of intersection i'll explane later) do the following:
first contour is the sequence of 2D points A1 A2 .... An and second contour is B1, B2, .., Bm, fix some i > 0 && i < n , j >0 && j < m and do extrapolation using (A1, ..., Ai) for finding extend from first endpoint of first contour than extrapolate (An-i, ...  ,An) for finding extendion of the first contour from second endpoint: do this similarly for second contour (B1, ... ,Bj) &&(Bm-j, ... , Bm) :
now you can extend your contours till borders of image and check are their intersect or not.
i hope you know how to find intersection of the segments in 2D space. You must use this for all [Ai Ai+1] and [Bj Bj+1] i = 1,... ,n-1 && j = 1,...,m-1